# How can I convert this output in this table format with Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I have this output data:

```
10dvex1_miRNA_ce.out.data|3331
10dvex1_misc_RNA_ce.out.data|0
10dvex1_rRNA_ce.out.data|60
10dvex1_snoRNA_ce.out.data|895
10dvex1_snRNA_ce.out.data|2127
11dvex1_miRNA_ce.out.data|3367
11dvex1_misc_RNA_ce.out.data|0
11dvex1_rRNA_ce.out.data|54
11dvex1_snoRNA_ce.out.data|839
11dvex1_snRNA_ce.out.data|1770
12dvex1_miRNA_ce.out.data|3321
12dvex1_misc_RNA_ce.out.data|0
12dvex1_rRNA_ce.out.data|50
12dvex1_snoRNA_ce.out.data|854
12dvex1_snRNA_ce.out.data|1821
```

I want to convert this output in this format, like as table:

```
`Fragment \t miRNA \t misc_RNA \t rRNA \t snRNA \t snoRNA`
 10 \t 3331 \t 0 \t 60 \t 2127 \ 895 \n
 11 \t 3367 \t 0 \t 54 \t 1770 \t 839 \n
 12 \t 3321 \t 0 \t 50 \t 1821 \t 854 \n
```

I need to use this table as Input to R. Some ideas? I try with perl with this script, but the result aren´t good:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open(MYINPUTFILE, $ARGV[0]); # open for input
my @lines = <MYINPUTFILE>; # read file into list
print "Frag"."\t"."miRNA"."\t"."misc_RNA"."\t"."rRNA"."\t"."snRNA"."\t"."snoRNA"."\n";
foreach my $lines (@lines){
    my $pattern = $lines;
    $pattern =~ s/(.*)dvex\d_(.*)_(.*)\|(.*)/$1 $2  $4/g;
    print $1."\t".$4;
}
close(MYINPUTFILE);
exit;
```

And the result:

```
Frag    miRNA   misc_RNA    rRNA    snRNA   snoRNA
10  333110  010 6010    89510   212711  336711  011 5411    83911   177012  332112  012 5012
```

Isn't the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works. It will wrap when the fragment number changes. It assumes that the order of the data always corresponds with the order of the headers.

```
open(MYINPUTFILE, $ARGV[0]); # open for input
my @lines = <MYINPUTFILE>; # read file into list
print "Frag"."\t"."miRNA"."\t"."misc_RNA"."\t"."rRNA"."\t"."snRNA"."\t"."snoRNA";
my $frag = '';
foreach my $line (@lines){
    if ( $line =~ /^(\d+)dvex.*\|(\d+)/ ) {
        my $fr = $1;
        if ( $fr ne $frag ) {
            print "\n$fr";
            $frag = $fr;
        }
        print "\t".$2;
    }
}
print "\n";
close(MYINPUTFILE);
exit;
```

Output looks like:

```
Frag    miRNA   misc_RNA        rRNA    snRNA   snoRNA
10      3331    0       60      895     2127
11      3367    0       54      839     1770
12      3321    0       50      854     1821
```

Comment: Excellent result! thanks a lot! I'm perl begginer, but im very excited. Thanks.

Comment: be careful with this, though, the order of the input file must match the header order. Upon closer inspection, the above output has the columns snoRNA and snRNA swapped. A better script would extract the headers from the data file and not care what order it was in.

Comment: The O'Reilly "Programming Perl" book by Wall, Christiansen, & Schwartz is still the best IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just missing a carriage return in your print statement. E.g.,

```
print $1."\t".$4."\n";
```

Comment: Maybe, but, the result is printed now in one column, i need to print the values in their respective column (or in their respective RNA).

Comment: ah, I see. You'll have to trigger when the "group" changes, e.g. from 10 -> 11, etc. This trigger will have you print the "group", and a carriage return.

Are you guaranteed that the order of the lines in the data file will always be in the same order as you headers?

Comment: The order can change, in this particular case, the order is for column 1, but it can be change with a preliminar 'sort -n' with bash commands...any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
print $1."\t".$4;
print "\n" if ($2 eq "snRNA");
```

Break the line whenever you get the pattern "snRNA";

Answer (score 0):

This one doesn't care what order the file is in, and extracts the headers from the data. The strategy is to accumulate the data into a structure, then output everything at once after all the data has been examined. If you have really (REALLY) big files, you could eat up memory.

```
open(MYINPUTFILE, $ARGV[0]); # open for input
my @lines = <MYINPUTFILE>; # read file into list
close(MYINPUTFILE);

## parse the data
my $types_found = {};
my $data = {};
foreach my $line (@lines){
    if ( $line =~ /^(\d+)dvex\d+_(.+)_ce\.out\.data\|(\d+)/ ) {
        $types_found->{$2} = '';
        $data->{$1}{$2} = $3;
    }
}

## print the header
my @types = sort keys %$types_found;
print "Frag";
foreach my $type ( @types ) {
    print "\t" . $type;
}
print "\n";

## print the rows
foreach my $frag ( sort keys %$data ) {
    print $frag;
    foreach my $type ( @types ) {
        print "\t" . $data->{$frag}{$type};
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

output:

```
Frag    miRNA   misc_RNA        rRNA    snRNA   snoRNA
10      3331    0       60      2127    895
11      3367    0       54      1770    839
12      3321    0       50      1821    854
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that orders the columns as requested by the OP:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my @header = qw (Frag miRNA misc_RNA rRNA snRNA snoRNA);

/(\d+).+?_(.+)_ce.+\|(.+)/ and $hash{$1}{$2} = $3 for <>;

print +( join "\t", @header ) . "\n";

for my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash ) {
    my @line;
    push @line, $hash{$key}{ $header[$_] } for 1 .. $#header;
    print +( join "\t", $key, @line ) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Frag    miRNA   misc_RNA    rRNA    snRNA   snoRNA
10  3331    0   60  2127    895
11  3367    0   54  1770    839
12  3321    0   50  1821    854
```